# HadoopYarn job setProgress

Tags: java, hadoop

I just want to know, how Hadoop MapReduce calculate the job/map/reduce progress when running an application.I can't properly find the answer through the "hadoop-2.7.4-src" source files.

For example, the following function is in

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobState;
/**
  * Sets the map progress of this job
  * @param p The value of map progress to set to
  */
protected synchronized void setMapProgress(float p) { 
    this.mapProgress = (float) Math.min(1.0, Math.max(0.0, p)); 
}
```

I dont' know which class call this function and how to calculate in detail.

I really want to know that because I try to find a reliable forecast method about mapreduce job's execution time.